# docker cp remotely (from container to host)

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm attempting to create a Jenkins job that remotely runs "docker cp" to copy a folder from the running container to the host machine.

Currently I have

`docker run --rm docker:1.7.1 docker -H stuff.dev.blah.com:5000 cp cc_head:/opt/blah/build/cc_head/games /home/devadmin/games`

But that doesn't work..

- So, the machine host is *stuff.dev.blah.com*, and I can ssh to it with `ssh devadmin@stuff.dev.blah.com`
- and at the host machine `docker cp cc_head:/opt/blah/build/cc_head/games /home/devadmin/games` works
- All we can have here is docker 1.7.1, but if you manage to do this with a newer version I'd also be happy
- the running container is called cc_head

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

**Mount the folder in cc_head container**

Where you run the container cc_head and add `-v /home/devadmin/games:/somefolder` while running the same

```
docker run --rm docker:1.7.1 docker -H stuff.dev.blah.com:5000 cp cc_head:/opt/blah/build/cc_head/games cc_head:/somefolder
```

**Mount the folder in separate container**

Run another container on the host and map the `/home/devadmin/games` and use that for the copy operation

```
docker run --rm docker:1.7.1 docker -H stuff.dev.blah.com:5000 cp cc_head:/opt/blah/build/cc_head/games container:/somefolder
```

Comment: I mounted a folder using -v :)
`docker run --rm docker:1.7.1 docker -H stuff.dev.blah.com:5000 run -v /home/devadmin/games:/somefolder ...(rest of my run command I was running already)...`